# How to interpret and use the values of the message type 'sensor_msgs/LaserScan'?

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, ros-hydro, base-laser, stage-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using the following package: stage_ros

http://wiki.ros.org/stage_ros

and the node stageros. I want to understand the topic published 'base_scan' that has a message type of 'sensor_msgs/LaserScan'

http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html

That message has a field 'float32[] ranges' but it doesn't specify the length of the array. I found the following pdf

[http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~yiannis/417/2011/COMP-417Fall2011Assignment1.pdf](http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/%7Eyiannis/417/2011/COMP-417Fall2011Assignment1.pdf)

which demostrates how to iterate the array, calculating the following indexes:

```
unsigned int minIndex = ceil((MIN_SCAN_ANGLE_RAD - msg->angle_min) / msg->angle_increment);
unsigned int maxIndex = ceil((MAX_SCAN_ANGLE_RAD - msg->angle_min) / msg->angle_increment);
```

They are using the angle_min and the angle_increment to calculate the indexes that later they will use to iterate over the array. I don't understand what those operations are doing but the final values are: minIndex = 501 and maxIndex = 580 which I think are the values that are in front of the robot.

Can someone explain this to me please?

Best,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206449/how-to-interpret-and-use-the-values-of-the-message-type-%27sensor_msgs/laserscan%27?/) by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 188 on 2015-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In C++, variable-length ROS message types are implemented as std::vector ([source](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Fields)). So you should be able to do

```
for (int i = 0; i < msg->ranges.size(); i++)
  float r = msg->ranges[i];
```

or

```
for (std::vector<float>::iterator it = msg->ranges.begin(); it != ms->ranges.end(); ++it)
  float r = *it;
```

*Disclaimer: I haven't actually tried running this exact code.*

---

Originally posted by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) with karma: 438 on 2015-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4